# Connecting to Open LDAP fails to bind with System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

Tags: binding, openldap, directoryservices

I have been trying to connect to Open LDAP using sample code from  MSDN (Alex Tcherniakhovski)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alextch/archive/2012/05/07/sample-code-to-query-openldap-directory-via-net-system-directoryservices-protocols.aspx

I have tried on PORT 636 : ssl as it is in the sample code

And on PORT 389 non ssl to see if i could succeed

When trying on  PORT 389 (with the same credentials I could connect to the OPEN LDAP using Softerra LDAP Browser)

I get the following error  : The distinguished name contains invalid syntax.

I ran Microsoft Network Monitor and found out that some unwanted characters ââ get added to my Bind request just before my name.  These characters never appear in the dotnet solution yet they are part of the request and make it fail.

Do you have an idea of how to get rid of these ?

I would have shown an image but i am not allowed.

My monitor shows BindRequest: Version:3, Name:ââcn=Manager,dc=...

in the dotnet code name is "cn=Manager,dc=.."

Using the code as is with SSL on port 636 lead to the following error : The LDAP server is unavailable.

I get the same error trying to connect with sslbind from Solution DirectoryServices.Protocol downloaded from here.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18086

Thanks for your help

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;



namespace OpenLDAPNextUID
{
public class LDAPHelper
{
    private readonly LdapConnection ldapConnection;
    private readonly string searchBaseDN;
    private readonly int pageSize;

    public LDAPHelper(
        string searchBaseDN,
        string hostName,
        int portNumber,
        AuthType authType,
        string connectionAccountName,
        SecureString connectionAccountPassword,
        int pageSize)
    {

        var ldapDirectoryIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(
            hostName,
            portNumber,
            true,
            false);

        var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(
            connectionAccountName,
            connectionAccountPassword);

        ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(
            ldapDirectoryIdentifier,
            networkCredential) 
            {AuthType = authType};

        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

        this.searchBaseDN = searchBaseDN;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SearchResultEntryCollection> PagedSearch(
        string searchFilter,
        string[] attributesToLoad)
    {

        var pagedResults = new List<SearchResultEntryCollection>();

        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
                (searchBaseDN,
                 searchFilter,
                 SearchScope.Subtree,
                 attributesToLoad);


        var searchOptions = new SearchOptionsControl(SearchOption.DomainScope);
        searchRequest.Controls.Add(searchOptions);

        var pageResultRequestControl = new PageResultRequestControl(pageSize);
        searchRequest.Controls.Add(pageResultRequestControl);

        while (true)
        {
            var searchResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(searchRequest);
            var pageResponse = (PageResultResponseControl)searchResponse.Controls[0];

            yield return searchResponse.Entries;
            if (pageResponse.Cookie.Length == 0)
                break;

            pageResultRequestControl.Cookie = pageResponse.Cookie;
        }


    }
}
}




namespace OpenLDAP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var password = new[]{'P','a','s','s','w','@','r','d'};
            var secureString = new SecureString();
            foreach (var character in password)
                secureString.AppendChar(character);

            var baseOfSearch = "dc=fabrikam,dc=com";
            var ldapHost = "ubuntu.fabrikam.com";
            var ldapPort = 636; //SSL
            var ldapPort = 389; //not SSL
            var connectAsDN = "cn=admin,dc=fabrikam,dc=com";
            var pageSize = 1000;

            var openLDAPHelper = new LDAPHelper(
                baseOfSearch,
                ldapHost,
                ldapPort,
                AuthType.Basic, 
                connectAsDN,
                secureString,
                pageSize);

            var searchFilter = "nextUID=*";
            var attributesToLoad = new[] {"nextUID"};
            var pagedSearchResults = openLDAPHelper.PagedSearch(
                searchFilter,
                attributesToLoad);

            foreach (var searchResultEntryCollection in pagedSearchResults)
                foreach (SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry in searchResultEntryCollection)
                    Console.WriteLine(searchResultEntry.Attributes["nextUID"][0]);

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 to get you closer to being able to attach an image.

Comment: Does anyone know where to get the password value in Active Directory?

Comment: For anyone coming back to this: [SecureString isn't recommended anymore](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) on .NET Core. If you're running into this same problem on .NET Framework, test whether using a normal System.String in the NetworkCredential gives the same error. If it works, consider not using SecureString.